# Adding GoDaddy account to Outlook 2016 hangs

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, godaddy

I'm trying to help a friend connect to her GoDaddy hosted exchange account in Office 365 (Outlook 2016).

It's a brand new Dell XPS Windows 10 computer with Office 365 installed.

Starting Outlook results in being asked for an email address. After a little while, a window appears asking for credentials. The top left of the screen has the GoDaddy logo, so I guess autodiscover is working. The banner at the top of the screen says Office 365. I enter the email address and password and click on the Sign In button. A spinning logo appears next to Sign In and it just hangs. I left it for 30 minutes but it did not compete. Closing the window resulted in some options - enter a different email address, try again or troubleshoot. I tried several times with the same result.

Her old computer runs Outlook 2010 and this is working fine with GoDaddy. On a different computer running Outlook 2010, I set up a new Mail profile and added her GoDaddy account without any problem.

I ran the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer, selected Exchange Server and Outlook Connectivity and the test was successful.

Somehow (not sure how!) I got Outlook 2016 started but with no accounts configured. I went into File / Account Settings and tried adding the account there but with the same result. After entering the email address and password the window just hangs with the spinner going round.

Don't know what else to try! Any suggestions welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel, select Mail and set the Account up manually (NO Wizard). You need to know the Account Setup Parameters to do this which you can get from the Outlook 2010 Account setup.

[image]

Here are the Go Daddy settings for Setup

https://ca.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949

Comment: John. Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I try to add an account selecting the option "Manual setup or additional server types" I see just two options. "Outlook.com or Exchange ActiveSync compatible service" and "POP or IMAP". I don't think either is appropriate for connecting to a GoDaddy Exchange server. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the Go Daddy email settings and they look familiar to me. Try IMAP detailed settings.   https://ca.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949